# Stuck with getting the occupancy to change with the input and checking it against the capacity

Tags: c++

Here is my problem I set this program up and the thing I need it to do I cannot figure it out. I need to make a one argument method Change_Status that changes the  status of the room to the value of its argument. The method should verify that the argument value does not exceed the room capacity. If it does, the method should return -1. Here is the code that I wrote

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>


using namespace std;

class HotelRoom
{
 private:
string room_no;
int capacity;
int occupancy;
double rate;
   public:
HotelRoom();
HotelRoom(string, int,double, int);
string get_number();
int get_capacity();
int get_status();
double get_rate();
void change_rate(double);
bool change_status(int);

};  
    HotelRoom::HotelRoom (string room, int cap,double rt, int occup)
{
room_no = room;
capacity = cap;
occupancy = occup;
rate = rt;
}
string HotelRoom::get_number()
{
return room_no;
}
int HotelRoom::get_capacity()
{
return capacity;
}
int HotelRoom::get_status()
{
return occupancy;
}
double HotelRoom::get_rate()
{
return rate;
}
void HotelRoom::change_rate( double amount)
{
rate += amount;
}
bool HotelRoom::change_status(int occupancy)
{
bool result;
if (capacity <= occupancy )
{ occupancy = capacity ;
result = true;
}
else
    result = false;
return result;
 }


   int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])

{

cout << setprecision(2)
     << setiosflags(ios::fixed)
     << setiosflags(ios::showpoint);





int occupancy;
double amount;
string room = "123";
int capacity = 4;
double rate = 150.00;


cout << endl;
cout << "enter the number of guests: ";
cin >> occupancy;

HotelRoom guest ( room, capacity, rate, occupancy);

cout << endl;
cout << " Room number is " << guest.get_number() << endl << endl;
cout << " Room Capacity is " << guest.get_capacity () << endl << endl;
cout << " Room Rate is " << guest.get_rate() << endl << endl;
cout << " Room Occupancy is " << guest.get_status() 
     << endl << endl;

cout << endl;
cout << "enter the number of guests: ";
cin >> occupancy;

cout << endl;
cout << " Room number is " << guest.get_number() << endl << endl;
cout << " Room Capacity is " << guest.get_capacity() << endl << endl;
cout << " Room Rate is " << guest.get_rate() << endl << endl;
cout << " Room Occupancy is " << guest.get_status() 
     << endl << endl;


cout << endl;
cout << " Change room rate: ";
cin >> amount;

guest.change_rate(amount);

cout << endl;
cout << " Room number is " << guest.get_number() << endl << endl;
cout << " Room Capacity is " << guest.get_capacity() << endl << endl;
cout << " Room Rate is " <<  amount << endl << endl;
cout << " Room Occupancy is " << guest.get_status()
     << endl << endl;


    cout << endl;
cout << "enter the number of guests: ";
cin >> occupancy;
cout << endl;
cout << " Room number is " << guest.get_number() << endl << endl;
cout << " Room Capacity is " << guest.get_capacity() << endl << endl;
cout << " Room Rate is " <<  amount << endl << endl;
cout << " Room Occupancy is " << guest.get_status()
     << endl << endl;




system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I believe this is the relevant code?

```
    bool HotelRoom::change_status(int occupancy)
    {
        bool result;
        if (capacity <= occupancy )
        {
            occupancy = capacity ;
            result = true;
        }
        else
            result = false;
        return result;
    }
```

There are a few problems here. The first is that the boolean logic is broken. You are checking if the capacity is less than or equal to the intended occupancy... it should be the other way around.

The second problem is that you're always setting the occupancy to the capacity. If the hotel has a capacity of 100, and you call `change_status(50)`, the occupancy should change to 50, not 100.

And the last problem is that when you set `occupancy` in the function, you're referring to the variable `occupancy` which is an argument to the function. Function scope takes precedence over class scope. So you should give the argument a different name, or use `this->occupancy` to refer to the member variable. So a revised version is:

```
    bool HotelRoom::change_status(int occupancy)
    {
        if (occupancy <= capacity)
        {
            this->occupancy = occupancy;
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
```